# Supporting one build for Android 3.0,4.0 and Android 2.2

Tags: android

I am facing a problem, I have to use one new API "BluetoothProfile" which is available for Android 3.0+. However if I use it I cant use my app anymore on Froyo or GingerBread.
Can someone suggest what are the options if I want to still support one build for all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

1. build your application usng Android 3.0+ (API 11)
2. define minSdkVersion = 8 in AndroidManifest.xml
3. retrieve and compare device android version, and restrict application function.

In your code:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
  Log.i(TAG, "Your android is too old, please upgrade.")
} else{
  Log.i(TAG, "meet the minimum system requirement")
}
```

check out the API [Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) and [Build.VERSION_CODES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)

Comment: are you trying to say I would need user to upgrade their android version?

Comment: OK, how about that "Your android is too old, BluetoothProfile function is restricted, sorry about that"

Comment: By setting the minSDKVersion you allow anyone with that version or newer to use your app. You can then compile against the 3.0 sdk. however you need to be careful to protect all 3.0 code with runtime checks to prevent it from running on unsupported handsets. The API analysis plugin may should help with this (though I've not used it myself) http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/